# Unindentified SQL error syntax with SpringBoot and JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

The compilation of my SpringBoot app fails to create a database.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'read bit, releaseDate date,
>   primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB' at line 1

According to the stack, it's from my "releaseDate" Date or my "read" boolean in my class "Book". I assume it fails with Jpa due to wrong annotations. (and that's pretty wide assumption, correct meif I am wrong)

Here is the stack

```
2019-01-21 14:29:21.482  INFO 5472 --- [           main] c.e.S.restapi.postgresql.Application     : Starting Application on MSI with PID 5472 (D:\Documents\Coding\Grokonez\clientVue_appRestFulSpringBoot_dataPostGre\SpringBootRestPostgreSQL\target\classes started by Charles LeMagnifique in D:\Documents\Coding\Grokonez\clientVue_appRestFulSpringBoot_dataPostGre\SpringBootRestPostgreSQL)
2019-01-21 14:29:21.486  INFO 5472 --- [           main] c.e.S.restapi.postgresql.Application     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-21 14:29:22.216  INFO 5472 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-01-21 14:29:22.280  INFO 5472 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 58ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-01-21 14:29:22.565  INFO 5472 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$81d566ae] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-01-21 14:29:22.835  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-01-21 14:29:22.855  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-01-21 14:29:22.855  INFO 5472 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
2019-01-21 14:29:22.861  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : An older version [1.2.17] of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat recommends a minimum version of [1.2.19]
2019-01-21 14:29:22.861  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.17] using APR version [1.6.3].
2019-01-21 14:29:22.861  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
2019-01-21 14:29:22.861  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
2019-01-21 14:29:23.900  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018]
2019-01-21 14:29:24.001  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-01-21 14:29:24.001  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2462 ms
2019-01-21 14:29:24.123  INFO 5472 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-01-21 14:29:24.628  INFO 5472 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-01-21 14:29:24.662  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-01-21 14:29:24.711  INFO 5472 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.1.Final}
2019-01-21 14:29:24.712  INFO 5472 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-01-21 14:29:24.773  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.3.Final}
2019-01-21 14:29:24.856  INFO 5472 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2019-01-21 14:29:24.901  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
2019-01-21 14:29:25.448  WARN 5472 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table Book (id bigint not null, description longtext, name varchar(255), read bit, releaseDate date, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table Book (id bigint not null, description longtext, name varchar(255), read bit, releaseDate date, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.Spring.restapi.postgresql.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read bit, releaseDate date, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB' at line 1
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:782) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:666) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.3.0.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.3.0.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
```

My application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

My pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.4</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

my class Book

```
package com.example.Spring.restapi.postgresql.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@Entity
//@Table(name = "table")
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "releaseDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date releaseDate;

    @Column(name = "read")
    @NotNull
    private boolean read;

    @Lob
    private String description;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String name, Date releaseDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.read = false;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }
    public void setReleaseDate(Date releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public boolean isRead() {
        return read;
    }
    public void setRead(boolean read) {
        this.read = read;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", releaseDate=" + releaseDate +
                ", read=" + read +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Below are the solutions I have tried:

- dialect MySQL8 in application.properties and pom.xml
- last version of Hibernate core in pom.xml
- adding annotations NotNull for boolean and Temporal for Date in my class Book

Comment: Hi, have you tried: @Entity @Table(name = "book") on top of the class? And maybe you need to declare the column name for property "description" as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the problem is related to the `READ` reserved keyword, see :

[Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R)

Comment: perfect thank you, we just solved it. Devil is in the details :/

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `read` as name here if you change the `read` name to something else it will work fine:

```
#new query
CREATE TABLE Book (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  description LONGTEXT,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  checked BIT, #little change
  releaseDate DATE,
  primary key (id)
) engine = InnoDB


//Code
@Column(name = "checked") //setting name to "checked"
private int read;
```

That is caused because there is a keyword `READ` in sql itself.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to

```
   @Column(name = "checked")
   @NotNull
   private boolean read;
```